# (Windows10) Netbeans 8.2 no detecta mi JDK

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, windows10

Ya tengo el JDK correctamente instalado pero el IDE no me lo detecta. Estuve googleando y aparentemente tengo que editar el archivo `tmcbeans.conf` pero en el mío no están las lineas de código que aparentemente los demás tienen.
 También algunos proponen agregar una linea de código indicando la ubicación de mi JDK pero están en formato iOS y Ubuntu. Por otra parte, fui a la ubicación del JDK, copie el directorio y lo pegué en la configuración pero no funciona aún. Alguna sugerencia?

Esta es la linea que debería haber en mi config:

```
 netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

A continuación el contenido de mi netbeans.conf:

```
# DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.
#
# Copyright 2005, 2016 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# Oracle and Java are registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates.
# Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
#
# The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
# General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common
# Development and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the
# "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the
# License. You can obtain a copy of the License at
# http://www.netbeans.org/cddl-gplv2.html
# or nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP. See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
# License.  When distributing the software, include this License Header
# Notice in each file and include the License file at
# nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP.  Oracle designates this
# particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
# by Oracle in the GPL Version 2 section of the License file that
# accompanied this code. If applicable, add the following below the
# License Header, with the fields enclosed by brackets [] replaced by
# your own identifying information:
# "Portions Copyrighted [year] [name of copyright owner]"
#
# If you wish your version of this file to be governed by only the CDDL
# or only the GPL Version 2, indicate your decision by adding
# "[Contributor] elects to include this software in this distribution
# under the [CDDL or GPL Version 2] license." If you do not indicate a
# single choice of license, a recipient has the option to distribute
# your version of this file under either the CDDL, the GPL Version 2 or
# to extend the choice of license to its licensees as provided above.
# However, if you add GPL Version 2 code and therefore, elected the GPL
# Version 2 license, then the option applies only if the new code is
# made subject to such option by the copyright holder.

# ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/8.2.0"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/8.2.0"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="--branding tmcbeans -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=256m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
# for 8.2.0elopment purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"

# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
#extra_clusters=


--jdkhome "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2"
```

(agregué yo mismo esa ultima linea con el jdkhome)

Comment: Hola. Esa no es la linea que deberías de tener. Pon la ruta donde esta instalado el jdk. Debe decir algo como c:\Program Files\...   también indicame que te sale en el archivo netbeas.conf que debe estar en el directorio etc de tu instalación de NetBeans.

Comment: hola Alvaro, revisa el post, lo actualicé con el contenido de la config

Comment: Falta la ruta al */bin*

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer debería bastar con sustituir la linea:

```
jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

Por

```
jdkhome="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10.0.2"
```

La linea que tu pusiste deberías quitarla.